# Entering N/A into People and Group Column

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, column, people-picker

I created a required People and Group column.  Is there a way to enter "N/A" or a sample name instead of entering a active name from the AD?  Its a required field can't leave it blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't. The field must resolve to an active user (in your case, Active Directory). You could create a "sample" user in AD but the account must be in an enabled state.